# onClick button switches between two components (react context)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

I am struggling to write `SwitchContext` and/or `SwitchButton` so that the `SwitchButton` makes toggling between components `MenuOne` and `MenuTwo` happen.

I tried to put an `IF ELSE` statement in `SwitchContext` with a `value`, and then when that `value` is `true` (in `SwitchButton`), it would switch to `MenuOne` and when `false` then switch to `MenuTwo`. But that did not work. How to make it?

`Layout.tsx`:

```
<div>
 <SwitchContext>
  <SwitchButton />
   <div><!-- switch MenuOne <> MenuTwo --></div>
 </SwitchContext>
</div>
```

`MenuOne` (and `MenuTwo` is the same but with different content):

```
"use client";
export default function MenuOne() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>MenuOne</p>
    <div>);}
```

`SwitchContext.tsx`: (Question: How to write `SwitchContext.tsx` so that toggling happens between component `MenuOne` and `MenuTwo` when clicking `SwitchButton`?):

```
"use client";
import MenuOne from "./MenuOne";
import MenuTwo from "./MenuTwo";
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const SwitchContext = createContext(false);

export default function SwitchContext({children,}: {children: React.ReactNode;}) {
  const [switch, setSwitch] = useState(true);
  const switchFunction =  ()  =>  {
    setSwitch(!switch);
  return (
    <SwitchContext.Provider value={{ switch, switchFunction }}>
      {children}
    </SwitchContext.Provider>
  );
}
export function useSwitchContext() {
  return useContext(SwitchContext);
}
```

`SwitchButton` (Question: How to write `SwitchButton.tsx` so that toggling happens between component `MenuOne` and `MenuTwo` when clicking `SwitchButton`?):

```
"use client";
import MenuOne from "./MenuOne";
import MenuTwo from "./MenuTwo";

export default function Switch() {
  const { switch, setSwitch } = useSwitchContext();
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={() => setSwitch(!switch)}</button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mindset of creating `SwitchContext.tsx` is utterly correct. But I couldn't understand why you imported the `MenuOne` and the `MenuTwo` there!

Also, your initial value isn't aligned with your pass value, and you have a curly brace syntax mistake. I'll fix both now:

```js
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

type SwitchContextType = {
  switch: boolean;
  switchFunction: () => void;
};

// Here is the initial value issue
const SwitchContext = createContext<SwitchContextType>({
  switch: false,
  switchFunction: () => {},
});

export default function SwitchContext({children,}: {children: React.ReactNode;}) {
  const [switch, setSwitch] = useState(true);

  const switchFunction =  ()  =>  {
    setSwitch(!switch);
  }; // Here is the missed curly brace

  return (
    <SwitchContext.Provider value={{ switch, switchFunction }}>
      {children}
    </SwitchContext.Provider>
  );
};

export function useSwitchContext() {
  return useContext(SwitchContext);
}; // By this lovely hook, you will pass the switch and the
// switchFunction everywhere, nothing else!
```

And inside the switch button should be exactly like the following, not the one you wrote:

```js
// Still here, it's not needed to import the MenuOne or MenuTwo

export default function Switch() {
  const { switchFunction } = useSwitchContext();

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={switchFunction}</button>
  );
}
```

Now, it is time to toggle between the `MenuOne` and the `MenuTwo`:

```js
// Layout.tsx

import MenuOne from "./MenuOne";
import MenuTwo from "./MenuTwo";

const Layout = () => {
  const { switch } = useSwitchContext();
  const Menu = switch ? MenuOne : MenuTwo;

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Menu />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

The above code `Layout.tsx` is a sample code to show you how to use the `useSwitchContext` and how to toggle between `MenuOne` and `MenuTwo` to render.

Answer (score 0):

MenutwoContext:

```
export default function MenutwoContextProvider({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const [menutwo, setMenutwo] = useState(true);

  const toggleMenutwo = () => {
    setMenutwo(!menutwo);
  };

  return (
    <MenutwoContext.Provider value={{ menutwo, toggleMenutwo }}>
      {children}
    </MenutwoContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Toggle:

```
export default function Toggle() {
  const { toggleMenutwo } = useMenutwoContext();

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="sticky top-0">
        <ButtonMenutwo />
        <h2>Title</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

ButtonMenutwo:

```
export default function ShowMenutwo() {
  const { toggleMenutwo } = useMenutwoContext();

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={toggleMenutwo}>
      Toggle Menu
    </button>
  );
}
```

Layout:

```
    <div className="relative h-[100vh] overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll">
      <MenutwoContextProvider>
        <Toggle />
        <div className="menu-container">
          {menutwo ? <MenuOne /> : <MenuTwo />}
        </div>
      </MenutwoContextProvider>
    </div>
```

MenuOne and MenuTwo:
You can keep these components as they are, focusing on their content and functionality.

Comment: does not work. And an explanation of your proposed solution would be nice, because I cannot make sense of it. Thanks.

Comment: Problem is in file "MenutwoContext" and specifically that it cannot find name "MenutwoContext".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).